# How to extract several data from a file and store it in a csv file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file in the following format :

```
19-08-02  Name                         appel    ok    hope    local  merge   (mk)
                                                        juin    nov    sept    oct
00:00:t1  T1                            299       0      24      8      3     64
          F2                            119       0      11      8      3     62
          I1                             25       0       2      9      4     64
          F3                            105       0      10      7      3     61
          Regulated F2                    0       0       0
          FR T1                         104       0      10      7      3     61
00:00:t2  T1                            649       0      24      8      3     64
          F2                            119       0      11      8      3     62
          I1                            225       0       2      9      4     64
          F3                            165       0      10      7      3     61
          Regulated F2                    5       0       0
          FR T1                         102       0      10      7      3     61
20-08-02  Name                          appel    ok    hope    local  merge   (mk)
                                                        juin    nov    sept    oct
00:00:t5  T1                            800       0      24      8      3     64
          F2                            111       0      11      8      3     62
          I1                             250      0       2      9      4     64
          F3                            105       0      10      7      3     61
          Regulated F2                    0       0       0
          FR T1                         100       0      10      7      3     61
```

and I want to extract some data and write them in an other file `CSV file` in the following format :

```
            T1   F2     I1      F3    Regulated F2    FR T1
00:00:t1    299  119    25      105       0           104  
00:00:t2    649  119    225     165       5           102
00:00:t5    800  111    250     105       0           100
.......
```

I just need to extract the values in the  third field `appel` every `00:00:XX`
I've tried to use `awk` but I didn't succeed to have the right script especially the 5th is composed of two words  : `Regulated F2`. 
I don't know how to extract it as a single word .

Any help please !

Comment: if the columns are evenly spaced and length-wise fixed, you can try using `cut -c 11-36` (assuming 2nd field is 25 characters, didn't count it) to extract the data. Likewise for the other fields

Comment: @MelBurslan Thanks for your quick response :) .. I have tried `cut -c ` it extracts fields eventhough there are white spaces but the problem that it's displayed vertically .. I want it to be written horizentally as the example above.

Comment: yes @don_crissti

Comment: How are fields defined? Is it a tab-separated file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Perl:

```bsh
perl -lane 'BEGIN{ print("\t\tT1\tF2\tI1\tF3\tRegulated F2\tFR T1"); $, = "\t" } if($F[0] =~ /00:00:t[0-9]+/){ @f[0] = $F[0]; @f[1] = $F[2]; for($i = 2; $i < 7; $i++) { $_ = <>; @F=split(); if($i < 5){ $f[$i] = $F[1] }else{ $f[$i] = $F[2] } } print(@f) }' file
```

Expanded script (to be made executable with `chmod +x script.pl` and to be run with `./script.pl file`):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -lan
BEGIN {
    print("\t\tT1\tF2\tI1\tF3\tRegulated F2\tFR T1");
    $, = "\t"
}
if($F[0] =~ /00:00:t[0-9]+/) {
    $f[0] = $F[0];
    $f[1] = $F[2];
    for($i = 2; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $_ = <>;
        @F=split();
        if($i < 5) {
            $f[$i] = $F[1]
        }
        else {
            $f[$i] = $F[2]
        }
    }
    print(@f) 
}
```

You can adjust the header by modifying `print("\t\tT1\tF2\tI1\tF3\tRegulated F2\tFR T1");` and the output field separator by modifying `$, = "\t"`.

```
% cat file
19-08-02  Name                         appel    ok    hope    local  merge   (mk)
                                                        juin    nov    sept    oct
00:00:t1  T1                            299       0      24      8      3     64
          F2                            119       0      11      8      3     62
          I1                             25       0       2      9      4     64
          F3                            105       0      10      7      3     61
          Regulated F2                    0       0       0
          FR T1                         104       0      10      7      3     61
00:00:t2  T1                            649       0      24      8      3     64
          F2                            119       0      11      8      3     62
          I1                            225       0       2      9      4     64
          F3                            165       0      10      7      3     61
          Regulated F2                    5       0       0
          FR T1                         102       0      10      7      3     61
20-08-02  Name                          appel    ok    hope    local  merge   (mk)
                                                        juin    nov    sept    oct
00:00:t5  T1                            800       0      24      8      3     64
          F2                            111       0      11      8      3     62
          I1                             250      0       2      9      4     64
          F3                            105       0      10      7      3     61
          Regulated F2                    0       0       0
          FR T1                         100       0      10      7      3     61
% perl -lane 'BEGIN{ print("\t\tT1\tF2\tI1\tF3\tRegulated F2\tFR T1"); $, = "\t" } if($F[0] =~ /00:00:t[0-9]+/){ @f[0] = $F[0]; @f[1] = $F[2]; for($i = 2; $i < 7; $i++) { $_ = <>; @F=split(); if($i < 5){ $f[$i] = $F[1] }else{ $f[$i] = $F[2] } } print(@f) }' file
        T1  F2  I1  F3  Regulated F2    FR T1
00:00:t1    299 119 25  105 0   104
00:00:t2    649 119 225 165 5   102
00:00:t5    800 111 250 105 0   100
%
```

Answer (score 5):

The task is fairly straightforward: ignore lines that start with date or lines that contain month columns ; if the first line contains time of the test, grab that time and the third column; for all the other lines - grab second column. The `AWK` script bellow does exactly that.

**Demo:**

```
$> ./data2cvs.awk  testData.txt                                                  
T1,F2,I1,F3,Regulated F2,FR T1
00:00:t1,299,119,25,105,0,104
00:00:t2,649,119,225,165,5,102
00:00:t5,800,111,250,105,0,100
```

**Script source**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

BEGIN {  
  HEADER="T1,F2,I1,F3,Regulated F2,FR T1"; print HEADER  
} 
# Ignore lines containing date and month
$1~/^[[:digit:]]{2}-.+/ || $0~/juin.*nov.*sept.*oct/ { 
     next ; 
}  
# Grab test time and first data value 
# Essentially doing something like sprintf in C
# to a string of arrays
$1~/^[[:digit:]]{2}:.+/{ 
     count++
     DATA[count]=$1","$3 
  }   
# grab remaining data values
$1 !~ /^[[:digit:]]{2}:.+/{

   if ($1~/Regulated/ || $1~/FR/){ 
      DATA[count]=DATA[count]","$3
   }
   else {
       DATA[count]=DATA[count]","$2 ;
   }
} 
# print gathered data to STDIN
END{ 
   for (i=1;i<=count;i++) print DATA[i] 

}
```

Comment: awsome response !! thanks a lot @Serg . Just a question If I want to add an other field like `Regulated FR`  I make it like this?  : `if  ($1~/Regulated/ || $1~/FR/ || $1~/Regulated/ || $1~/ ENG/) ` ?

Comment: Well, what the original line does is to test if column number $1 has words regulated or FR. If you want " Regulated ENG" line , it will be found already, just because it has the word regulated. But if you are looking for something like "ENG xx", then add `if ($1~/ENG/) `.  It always depends on how your input text file looks like, so i cannot tell you how to program something i never seen

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment and your time, it helped me a lot  :)

Comment: Always glad to help :)